# Delphi: How to modify the Library Path?

Tags: delphi

Using D7.
Do you know of a better Library Path Editor than the one included in Delphi 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the Delphi 7 Companion Tools CD, look for "USG Freeware" or download from [here](http://cc.codegear.com/partners/delphi7disk1/dennis_passmore/usg_freeware/USGFreeware.zip):
Details [here](http://cc.codegear.com/partners/delphi7disk1/dennis_passmore/usg_freeware/index.html) :

Quote:

> LibPathEdit70.dll
>
> This is a Delphi 7 IDE addin package that adds enhanced
>   Library path and Project Search path
>   editing capabilities. Once installed
>   it will show up under the "Tools" menu
>   labeled "Library Path Editor". The top
>   Listbox displayed will provide the
>   ability to edit and save the default
>   Library path. The bottom Listbox
>   provides the ability to edit and save
>   the your Project specific Search and
>   Debug paths.

Also try:

[Library Path Editor](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/22305)

> Enhanced Library Path Editor IDE addin
>   expert (CDN Login Required to Download)

"[Library Search Path Editor](http://www.torry.net/vcl/experts/utilities/pathwiz.zip)"

or

"[AMNSoft Library Expert](http://www.torry.net/vcl/experts/utilities/anlibexp.zip)"

Comment: Can you download this?  I wasn't able to.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create your own.  You might have some grief if Delphi is open at the time, though.

Library path details are stored in the registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software.  I don't have Delphi 7 handy to track down the specific key, but here's where it is for Delphi 2010:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\Library

Answer (score 0):

Try HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0 ( be carefull with regedit if your operative system is 64 bits, remenber that Delphi 7 is a 32 bits Application, and you have to use the register editor that is inside of "C:\windows\syswow64(32)\Regedit.exe", don't use default register editor (64 bits in an operative system 64 bits)